# Is the coderay syntax-highlighting plugin built into redmine, or does it have to be installed separately?

Tags: ruby, syntax-highlighting, rubygems, redmine

I have installed a recent version of redmine - 3.3.3 but there is no syntax highlighting plugin included in the default installation.

Most redmine searches mention coderay. Is that something I have to install separately as a gem for the redmine installation to pick up automatically? ruby for it work?

Comment: I am not getting any syntax-highlighting on the source code, and the plugins directory is empty, but I have installed the coderay gem and I am wondering whether the coderay plugin is something built into redmine itself or needs to be installed additionally.

Comment: It turns coderay is already built in, but it doesn't support lisp and bash and that is why I thought it wasn't installed. They are both well known languages.